# Limiting physical memory of specifc process

Tags: ram, kill, resource-limiting

Performing research, I am interested in limiting the Physical Memory per specific process.

My requirements:

1. Limit physical memory consumption for specific program
2. In case of crossing limitation - don't kill the process! - just perform page-in - page-out.

I used many unix options without success.

`ulimit` sets the limit, but kills processes which cross them.
The cgroup approach has the same behavior.
Any ideas?